# Default search path for cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

I am a chef Newbie and facing an issue.

Every time I run any of the knife cookbook command, I have to explicitly provide the path to cookbook using `-o /path/to/cookbook` else it will error out saying no cookbooks found. Please find below commands:

```
$ knife cookbook upload getting-started
ERROR: Could not find cookbook getting-started in your cookbook path, skipping it
ERROR: Failed to upload 1 cookbook.

$ knife cookbook upload getting-started  -o /home/chefuser/chef11/chef-repo/cookbooks/
Uploading getting-started [0.4.0]
Uploaded 1 cookbook.
```

**Question**:

I want to know/list the default search path for cookbooks and need to know how to modify it.

Also, why it is not looking at cookbook path and I have to provide it explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Default cookbook path could be set in `~/.chef/knife.rb`:

```
...
cookbook_path [ '~/cookbooks/', '~/base-cookbooks/']
...
```

Also, you could find [knife.rb documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html) useful.

Comment: Can't thank you enough!! It saved me a lot of unnecessary typing.

Comment: This answer would benefit by specifying where knife.rb is located.

Comment: `knife.rb` can be found in the .chef folder of either your home directory, or the directory where your `cookbooks/` folder is, depending on how you set Chef up. If you don't have a `.chef/knife.rb`, you didn't run `knife configure --initial`. See the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-a-chef-server-workstation-and-client-on-ubuntu-vps-instances#WorkstationInstallation) for more details on how to initialize your workstation for Chef.

Comment: This blog has a better cookbook_path setup, i.e. the way you would expect it to work: https://www.coveros.com/setting-your-knife-rb-cookbook_path-to-match-your-cookbook-locations/

Comment: From @cbron link: setting `cookbook_path [ '.', '..','~/cookbooks/']` will look in local and parent directory for a match first.